# Background animation Vue Js / ES6

Tags: javascript, animation, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I was trying to insert my background animation on my webapp but I'm facing this message error.

```
Cannot set property 'width' of null
```

My web app is on Vue JS 2. I created a template tag with a canvas tag inside

```
<template>
  <canvas>
    <GlobalView></GlobalView>
  </canvas>
</template>
```

Inside my script tags and after the export default method I inserted my animation:

```
<script>
  import GlobalView from '@/GlobalView'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      GlobalView
    }
  }

  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
  const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
  const colors = ['#E0FBFC', '#FF5964', '#FFFFFF', '#38618C', '#C2DFE3']
  function Circle (x, y, r, dx, dy, color) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.r = r
    this.dx = dx
    this.dy = dy

    this.draw = function () {
      c.beginPath()
      c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
      c.fillStyle = color
      c.fill()
      if (this.y + this.r >= innerHeight || this.y - this.r <= 0) {
        this.dy = -this.dy
      }
      if (this.x + this.r >= innerWidth || this.x - this.r <= 0) {
        this.dx = -this.dx
      }
      this.x += this.dx
      this.y += this.dy
    }
  }

  const circles = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const r = (Math.random() * 30) + 10
    const x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - r * 2) + r
    const y = Math.random() * (innerHeight - r * 2) + r
    const dx = (Math.random() - 0.5)
    const dy = (Math.random() - 0.5)
    const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
    const circle = new Circle(x, y, r, dx, dy, color)
    circles.push(circle)
  }
  const drawCircle = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle)
    c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)
    circles.forEach((circle) => {
      circle.draw()
    })
  }

  drawCircle()
  canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      const r = (Math.random() * 30) + 10
      const dx = (Math.random() - 0.5)
      const dy = (Math.random() - 0.5)
      const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
      circles.push(new Circle(e.pageX, e.pageY, r, dx, dy, color))
    }
  })

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight
  })
</script>
```

It seems that it didn't recognise javascript methods like width, getContext or even clearRect.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code will run during module compilation before anything even remotely begins appearing in the document. You really want to add it to one of the [Vue lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) like `mounted`

Comment: Hi Phil, Thank you I see better now. 5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Of course it won't work, because you do not use methods and call it,

  <script>
  import GlobalView from '@/GlobalView'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      GlobalView
    },
    methods: {
        canvas () {
             const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
             canvas.width = window.innerWidth
             canvas.height = window.innerHeight
           ....
        }
    }
  }

//and then, call it,, vm = new Vue()
vm.canvas();
</script>
```